# How often to verify subscriptions for auto-renew subscriptions?

Tags: ios, xcode, auto-renewable

How often should I verify a auto renew subscriptions?

1x at every app launch? Meaning the customer presses the app icon and launches the app?

Or 1x when the app is initially launched then allow the app to reset in the background if it is not opened for a while? iOS will reset the app after some time. It will then recheck at launch again since the app was reset by iOS. If the customer comes back to the app before it is reset it will not need to check the subscription again.

Comment: I don't use subscription pricing, but why not set a variable (maybe in `UserDefaults`?) to track the expiration date? Then, combined with tracking the last date checked, you code to check every day when the app will enter foreground (depending on the target iOS version it's either in AppDelegate or SceneDelegate). I'm sure you could also do this "once a day" check against the receipt....

Comment: EDIT: I'm **not** saying you check it every single time the app will enter the foreground. I'm saying you check only if the date of the last check has changed, and you check that the subscription has not expired.